# Create website and child page simultaneously in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

On my homepage, I'm trying to set it up so when you click the "Get started" button, a website record is created, but also a page belonging to that website is created, and you're redirected to the page.

This is what I have so far. The website record is being created but the page is not being created.

Models

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :website
end

class Website < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pages, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages
end
```

Homepage controller

```
class MarketingPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @website = Website.new
        @website.pages.build
    end
end
```

Website controller

```
class WebsitesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @website = Website.new(creation_params)

        if @website.save
            redirect_to @website.Page.first
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

private

    def shared_params
        [:name]
    end

    def creation_params
        params.require(:website).permit(*shared_params)
    end

    def update_params
        params.require(:website).permit(*shared_params)
    end
end
```

Page Controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @page = Page.new(creation_params)

        if @page.save
            redirect_to @page
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def show
        @page = Page.find(params[:id])
        @templates = Template.all
    end

private

    def shared_params
        [:name, :website_id]
    end

    def creation_params
        params.require(:page).permit(*shared_params)
    end

    def update_params
        params.require(:page).permit(*shared_params)
    end
end
```

Website form on homepage

```
<%= form_for @website do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :name, value: "Untitled site" %>
    <%= f.fields_for :pages do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.hidden_field :name, value: "Untitled page" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Create Website" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the association incorrectly

```
# Change
@website.Page.first
# to
@website.pages.first
```

Change this snippet in `WebsiteController`

```
if @website.save
  redirect_to @website.pages.first
else
  render :new
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question to include the submit form. The page record is not being created.

Answer (score 0):

you have not white listed `page` params in `website controller`. modify your `shared_params` in `website controller` to :

```
def shared_params
  [:name, pages_attributes: [:id, :name]]
end
```

and of course do changes suggested by @Deepak

Comment: Thanks, I've made those changes now but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the error? Can I look in a console somewhere?

Comment: Yes, if it is not raising any error then look into the log in server console you may find whats happening.

Comment: you may have to whitelist `id` too.